# Using Ecto.Multi to update parent and and dynamically child records

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I have two objects, Logs and Blocks. Logs belong to Blocks - if a Log and a Block share a hashtag, then they’ll be linked together. The link is stored in the Log.

Updating Logs is fairly simple. However, if you edit the hashtags in a Block, then you have to update linked Logs and (potentially) update Logs that will be linked

To address this bulk update, I’m wrapping up database operations in a transaction via `Ecto.Multi`. However, I’m not sure of the best way to do this. This is my current version:

```
def update_block_then_logs( %Block{} = block, attrs, for: user ) do
  Ecto.Multi.new()
  |> Ecto.Multi.update( :block, Blocks.update_block(block, attrs) )
  |> Ecto.Multi.run( :logs, fn _repo, %{block: block} ->
    tags = block.tags |> String.split

    # Returns logs that are currently set to this block and logs that will be set
    log_changesets = list_logs_affected_by( block: block, tags: tags, for: user )
    |> Enum.map( fn log ->
      regenerate_blocks_for_log( log, for: user )
    end)

    errors = log_changesets
    |> Enum.filter( fn {status, _changeset} -> status == :error end )
    |> Enum.map( fn {_status, changeset} -> changeset end )

    if errors != nil && Enum.count(errors) > 0 do
      { :error, errors }
    else
      { :ok, log_changesets }
    end
  end)
  |> Repo.transaction
end
```

`regenerate_blocks_for_log` interrogates the database (and will assume that the Block has already been updated). It ends up calling `Repo.update( log_changeset )` rather than returning the changeset itself. Because I’m using `Ecto.Multi.run` I had to create some error trapping. The code I wrote seems okay, but then I thought it might be better for error trapping if I separated out each `Repo.update` into its own operation in the `Ecto.Multi` object.

So I created this version:

```
def update_block_then_logs( %Block{} = block, attrs, for: user ) do
  block_changeset = Blocks.update_block( block, attrs )

  multi = Ecto.Multi.new()
  |> Ecto.Multi.update( :block, block_changeset )

  tags = block_changeset 
  |> Ecto.Changeset.get_field( :tags )
  |> String.split

  # Returns logs that are currently set to this block and logs that will be set
  multi_log = list_logs_affected_by( block: block, tags: tags, for: user )
  |> Enum.map( fn log ->
    op_name = String.to_atom("log_#{log.id}")
    log_changeset = regenerate_blocks_for_log( log, for: user )

    Ecto.Multi.new
    |> Ecto.Multi.update( op_name, log_changeset )
  end)
  |> Enum.reduce( Ecto.Multi.new(), &Ecto.Multi.append/2 )

  Ecto.Multi.append( multi, multi_log )
  |> Repo.transaction()
end
```

In this version, `regenerate_blocks_for_log` returns a changeset. However, I realised that `regenerate_blocks_for_log` won’t work - since it was written to read data committed within a transaction (which doesn’t happen until the last statement).

I could adjust `regenerate_blocks_for_log` so that it takes into account changes to the Block that have not yet been committed. But then I wonder, is there a way to dynamically alter the `Multi` using the first technique (as records have been committed in the transaction)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer in the [original post](https://elixirforum.com/t/using-ecto-multi-to-update-parent-and-and-dynamically-child-records/19557) for this question. `Ecto.Multi.merge` allows you to append to the `Multi` while inside the transaction:

```
defp update_logs( block, for: user ) do
  tags = if block.tags == nil do [] else block.tags |> String.split end

  # Returns logs that are currently set to this block and logs that will be set
  list_logs_affected_by( block, tags, for: user )
  |> Enum.map( fn log ->
    op_name = String.to_atom("log_#{log.id}")
    log_changeset = regenerate_blocks_for_log( log, for: user )

    Ecto.Multi.new
    |> Ecto.Multi.update( op_name, log_changeset )
  end)
  |> Enum.reduce( Ecto.Multi.new(), &Ecto.Multi.append/2 )
end

def update_block_then_logs( %Block{} = block, attrs, for: user ) do
  Ecto.Multi.new()
  |> Ecto.Multi.update( :block, Blocks.update_block(block, attrs) )
  |> Ecto.Multi.merge( fn %{block: block} -> update_logs(block, for: user) end )
  |> Repo.transaction
end
```